# photo viewer oculus rift

Tags: visual-studio, directx, oculus

I need to create a project in visual studio that through directx 12 shows a 2d image in Oculus rift.
I just need to view an image from a file.
I'm new at this and I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Time for a crash course in unity - it won't take you long to get that up and running, start here: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/book-unity-gsg/

When you're used to it take a look at the VR book asset for some good ideas in where to go to make it better

Comment: I need to do it with directx 12, I don't need unity.